# Google Authentication using firebase in reactjs is not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-authentication

This is firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export default db;
export { auth, provider };
```

This is login.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./login.css";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import { auth, provider } from "./firebase";

function Login() {
  const signIn = () => {
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="login">
        <div className="login-container">
          <img
            src={
              "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/WhatsApp.svg"
            }
            alt=""
          />
          <div className="login-text">
            <h1>Sign In to WhatsApp Clone</h1>
          </div>
          <Button onClick={signIn}>SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Whenever I run the code, a window pops-up for google sign-in but it never shows anything at all. Even if I use signInWithRedirect the google auth never works. I never got any kindof errors in the console. Can anyone guide me pls...

Comment: You should probably rotate your firebase credentials after you just disclosed them publicly

Comment: Woa woa! Never post your API key on SO!

Comment: Never post your API keys *anywhere*.

Comment: yep i haven't & thanks

Comment: Did you get any errors in the console

Comment: Nope, no errors

Comment: Are you sure that you have enabled google authentication in auth section of firebase console

Comment: yes I have enavled google auth in firebase console

Answer (score 0):

I generally catch the errors using this method :

```
const signIn = () => {
    auth
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
  };
```

Or **you may not have enabled google authentication in the console yet.**

If its not any of these please post a codesandox link with the issue reproduced.